# Issue with deployment flask and apache2 mod_wsgi

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I'm just following everything they told in this [doc](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps) but haven't figured out why apache2 throwing below error.

```
root@Test1:/etc/apache2/sites-available# tail -5 /var/log/apache2/error.log 
[Sat Oct 17 04:22:13.518858 2015] [core:notice] [pid 28379] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sat Oct 17 04:22:18.930540 2015] [:error] [pid 28573] [client 223.190.213.33:33891] mod_wsgi (pid=28573): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/instanotify/instanotify.wsgi'.
[Sat Oct 17 04:22:18.930623 2015] [:error] [pid 28573] [client 223.190.213.33:33891] TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
[Sat Oct 17 04:43:26.664459 2015] [:error] [pid 28575] [client 223.190.213.33:34215] mod_wsgi (pid=28575): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/instanotify/instanotify.wsgi'.
[Sat Oct 17 04:43:26.664634 2015] [:error] [pid 28575] [client 223.190.213.33:34215] TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Update:

```
root@Test1:/var/www/instanotify# cat instanotify.wsgi 
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging
# Virutalenv activattion
activate_this = '/var/www/instanotify/instanotify/env/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/instanotify/")

from instanotify import app as application
application.secret_key = 'Add your secret key'
```

If I remove the virtualenv activation line I'm getting `no module named flask`

Is anybody know how to solve...! I'm very happy to provide the further information

Comment: Since the problem is in the instanotify.wsgi script, your should probably post that.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I just added... Looks somehow small import issue isn't it ?

Comment: OK please show the instanotify.py file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you didn't import actual `app` file... the correct way is

```
from instanotify.app import app as application
```